# Safari App Extension localized contextual menus

Tags: swift, safari, safari-app-extension

I have localized a Safari App Extension and everything works just fine, but I cannot get the contextual menus localized...

Following the Apple [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/safari_app_extension_info_property_list_keys/adjusting_settings_for_contextual_menu_items) I have come up with the following entry in my `InfoPlist.strings` file:

```
"Context Menu Item Label for Command: pause" = "Anhalten";
```

but this does nothing, and the unlocalized string is still shown. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file format was fine, but the *InfoPlist.strings* needed to be saved in the **UTF8** format
:(